# convert html code of radiobutton using rails helpers

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How can I achieve the below radiobutton in html using rails helpers?? I do have a field ***guests*** in my database where the selected value of the radio button gets stored.

```
<div class="segmented-control" style="width: 100%; color: #5FBAAC">
            <input type="radio" name="guests" id="1">
            <input type="radio" name="guests" id="2">
            <input type="radio" name="guests" id="3">
            <input type="radio" name="guests" id="4">
            <input type="radio" name="guests" id="5">
            <input type="radio" name="guests" id="6">

            <label for="1"  data-value="1">1</label>
            <label for="2" data-value="2">2</label>
            <label for="3" data-value="3">3</label>
            <label for="4"  data-value="4">4</label>
            <label for="5" data-value="5">5</label>
            <label for="6" data-value="6+">6</label>
 </div>
```

I tried using

```
<%= f.select  :guests, [["1","1"], ["2","2"], ["3","3"], ["4","4"],
["5","5"],["6","6"]], id: "guests", class: "form-control" %>
```

But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a helper method called `options_for_select` which transforms an array of arrays into select input options.

```
<%= f.select :guests, options_for_select([["1","1"],["2","2"],["3","3"],["4","4"],
["5","5"],["6","6"]]), id: "guests", class: "form-control" %>
```

documentation : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

Comment: This works but am looking for the same thing in a radiobutton

Comment: Have a look at the `collection_radio_buttons` method inside the documentation I linked. It should be what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it returns what you want:

```
<%1.upto(6) do |n|%>
   <%= radio_button_tag :guests, "#{n}",nil, id: "#{n}" %>
<%end%>

<%1.upto(6) do |n|%>
   <%= label_tag("#{n}", "#{n}", "data-tag"=>"#{n}") %>
<%end%>
```